# Replication data using vsphere esxi 6.0

Tags: vmware

I have a specific question about vmware esxi 6.0 which i have problem to make replication of data on 2 esxi has the similar type and how to change the domain name server of the 2 esxi.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standalone ESXi server? Do you have a vCenter server?

You can read a few manuals for replication.

vCenter replication
https://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vsphere/VMW-vSPHR-Replication-6-0.pdf

vSphere replication with different domains 
http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-replication-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.replication-admin.doc/GUID-08B7DF70-559C-429C-BC5F-8E08C6638E35.html

Alternative: You can use side products to replication like - Veeam